# Many to Many wherehas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to search a post that has a similar tag only with tags id number

I've tried this

```
$tags = Tag::find($id);
$post = Post::whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($id){
$q->where('id',$id);})->paginate(5);

    return view('tagdetail', compact('tags', 'post'));
```

but the output is SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (23000).

I've already search through the internet and still cant.

Tag.php

```
public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
    }
```

Post.php

```
public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
```

controller

```
public function detailTag($id)
    {
        //i know this will get all the post with the tag id, but i want to paginate it too. 
        $tags = Tag::find($id);

        $post = Post::whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($id){
    $q->where('id',$id);
})->paginate(5);

        return view('tagdetail', compact('tags', 'post'));
    }
```

The expected result: to show all post that has a similar tag with paginating.

Actual result : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (23000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this issue many times myself.  It's just asking you to clarify which table you are trying to compare the id within, `posts` or `tags`, since both tables have the same key (`id`).  Try this, I think it will solve your issue:

```
$post = Post::whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($id){
    $q->where('tags.id',$id); // ** call out the tags table specifically
})->paginate(5);
```

Comment: omg thank you so much, and thank you for the explanation, it does makes lot of sense now, thanks.